# What is the value of the expression $[1 + \cos(\frac{\pi}{8})][1 + \cos(\frac{3\pi}{8})][1 + \cos(\frac{5\pi}{8})][1 + \cos(\frac{7\pi}{8})]$?

Tags: trigonometry

*This is rather a simple problem that I'm posting ; looking forward not for the solution of it but the different ways it could be solved.*

What is the value of the following expression?

> $$\left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 5\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 7\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) $$

Edit: Do I manually put the values of $\cos\frac{\pi}{8}$ and all other cosine terms? Is there a better and shorter way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 5\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 7\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) =\\ =\left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \pi -\frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \pi -\frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) =\\ =\left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \left( \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1-\cos { \left( \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) \left( 1-\cos { \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  \right)  }  \right) =\\ =\left( 1-\cos ^{ 2 }{ \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  }  \right) \left( 1-\cos ^{ 2 }{ \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  }  \right) =\sin ^{ 2 }{ \frac { \pi  }{ 8 }  } \sin ^{ 2 }{ \frac { 3\pi  }{ 8 }  } =\frac { \left( 1-\cos { \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }  \right)  }{ 2 } \cdot \frac { \left( 1-\cos { \frac { 3\pi  }{ 4 }  }  \right)  }{ 2 } =\\ =\frac { \left( 1-\cos { \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }  \right) \left( 1-\cos { \left( \pi -\frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  \right)  }  \right)  }{ 4 } =\frac { \left( 1-\cos { \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }  \right) \left( 1+\cos { \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }  \right)  }{ 4 } =\frac { 1-\cos ^{ 2 }{ \frac { \pi  }{ 4 }  }  }{ 4 } =\frac { 1-\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }{ 4 } =\frac { 1 }{ 8 }  $$

Comment: Nicely done. Sometimes it's too simple to be actually accepted as simple by the brain.

Comment: As $\dfrac\pi8+\dfrac{3\pi}8=\dfrac\pi2,\sin\dfrac{3\pi}8=\cos\dfrac\pi8$ $$\implies\sin\dfrac\pi8\sin\dfrac{3\pi}8=\sin\dfrac\pi8\cos\dfrac\pi8=\dfrac{\sin\dfrac\pi4}2=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,thank you ,i couldn't see it)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\dfrac{1}{8}$

As $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$ we can write
$$\left(1+\cos\frac{\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1+\cos\frac{3\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1+\cos\frac{5\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1+\cos\frac{7\pi}{8}
\right)=\left(1+\cos\frac{\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1+\cos\frac{3\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1-\cos\frac{3\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1-\cos\frac{\pi}{8}
\right)=
\left(1-\cos^2\frac{\pi}{8}
\right)\left(1-\cos^2\frac{3\pi}{8}
\right)=\sin^2\frac{\pi}{8}\,\sin^2\frac{3\pi}{8}=\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{8}\,\sin\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)^2$$
For the Werner's formula 
$$\sin x\sin y=\frac{1}{2} (\cos (x-y)-\cos (x+y))$$
so 
$$\sin\frac{\pi}{8}\,\sin\frac{3\pi}{8}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos\frac{-\pi}{4}-\cos\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
Remember that
$\cos\dfrac{-\pi}{4}=\cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\dfrac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

So the result is $\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Like [The value of $\cos^4\frac{\pi}{8} + \cos^4\frac{3\pi}{8}+\cos^4\frac{5\pi}{8}+\cos^4\frac{7\pi}{8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645874/the-value-of-cos4-frac-pi8-cos4-frac3-pi8-cos4-frac5-pi8-c/645993#645993),

if $y=1+c,$ we have $$8(y-1)^4-8(y-1)^2+1=0\iff8y^4+\cdots+1=0$$

$$\implies\prod_{n=0}^3\left(1+\cos\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}8\right)=\dfrac18$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$
1+\cos\alpha=2\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2}
$$
If $\beta=\pi/16$ (so $8\beta=\pi/2$), you get
$$
16\cos^2\beta\cos^23\beta\cos^25\beta\cos^27\beta=
(2\cos\beta\cos7\beta)^2(2\cos3\beta\cos5\beta)^2
$$
Now, with the [product-to-sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities),
$$
2\cos\beta\cos7\beta=\cos8\beta+\cos6\beta=\cos6\beta
$$
and
$$
2\cos3\beta\cos5\beta=\cos8\beta+\cos2\beta=\cos2\beta
$$
Hence your expression is
$$
(\cos6\beta\cos2\beta)^2=
\frac{1}{4}(\cos8\beta+\cos4\beta)^2=
\frac{1}{4}\cos^2\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{8}
$$